# Difficulty with using truetype font symbols in Mapserver

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, mapserver

I am basically following this [workflow](http://simonmercier.net/blog/?tag=symbol) and having no luck. I have add a truetype font file to my fonts.list (under the alias 'ddv') however, I cannot get the fonts to render in the service. Any ideas, maybe...?

```
    # ma_interstate_labels.map

########## English ##########
  LAYER
    NAME "county_labels"
    GROUP 'county_labels'
    TYPE ANNOTATION
    STATUS DEFAULT
    DATA "ROADS_PT_MA_Interstate_3785.shp"
    LABELITEM "RTE_NUM1"
    # Visible in map from zoom level 6 onwards
    MAXSCALEDENOM 10400256
    MINSCALEDENOM 2539
    # shell symbol
    SYMBOL
      NAME shell
      TYPE truetype
      FONT "ddv"
      CHARACTER "&#35;"   
    END
    CLASS
       STYLE
         SYMBOL shell
         ANTIALIAS TRUE
       END
      LABEL
       TYPE truetype
       FONT "deja"
       SIZE 5
       COLOR 52 88 133
       ALIGN center
       WRAP " "
       MAXLENGTH 4
       ANGLE 0
       PARTIALS FALSE
       END # end label
    END # end class
  END # end of layer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your "shell" symbol definition (i.e. the SYMBOL .. END block) should be at the MAP level, not the LAYER level as you have it now.
- in your STYLE..END block, you should add a SIZE and a COLOR entry